# How can I run "RECONFIGURE" in Linq-to-Entities?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm using SQL Server via Linq-to-Entities.

And I need to change Sql configuration and reconfigure but with Linq-to-Entities, it cannot be run.

```
    entity.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE
EXEC sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1
RECONFIGURE
    ");
```

and it shows like this.

> SqlException: CONFIG statement cannot be used inside a user transaction.

Is there any possible way that I can run this query via entity?

Comment: Is there no way Linq-to-Entities can not let you say "run this ExecuteSqlCommand() without wrapping it in a transaction"? If not, genius.

Comment: Did you try using the overload for [ExecuteSqlCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.database.executesqlcommand?view=entity-framework-6.2.0#System_Data_Entity_Database_ExecuteSqlCommand_System_Data_Entity_TransactionalBehavior_System_String_System_Object___) wit the [TransactionalBehavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.transactionalbehavior?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) set to `DoNotEnsureTransaction`?  Also [tag:linq-to-entities] does not work with databases so I'm sure you meant [tag:entity-framework].